# react navigation 5 hide bottom tab nav in nested navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-bottom-tab

The structure of my react navigation is like this : BottomTabNavigator => Navigator => Components

This is the skeleton of the App.js. The whole application is wrapped up in a bottom tab navigation.

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function App() {
  return (  
    <NavigationContainer>     
      <BottomTab.Navigator >
        <BottomTab.Screen
          name="Main"
          component={MyVeranda}
          options={{
            tabBarLabel: 'Home',
            tabBarIcon: //...some icon,
          }}
        />
        //...some other screens
      </BottomTab.Navigator>          
    </NavigationContainer>  
  );
}

export default App;
```

As you can see, inside the bottom tab i have screen name "Main" that uses `MyVeranda` component. `MyVeranda` itself is a stack navigator, which have 2 screens components : `MyHome` and `BuyForm`

```
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator();

function MyVeranda({ route,navigation }) {
  //..some states, props, etc

  return (
    <HomeStack.Navigator>
        <HomeStack.Screen
            name="MyHome"
            component={MyHome}
            options={{/*...some options*/ }}
        />  
        <HomeStack.Screen
            name="BuyItem"
            component={BuyForm}
            options={{/*...some options*/}}
        />
    </HomeStack.Navigator>
  );
}

export defaul MyVeranda;
```

`MyVeranda` is a parent of `MyHome` and `BuyForm`, both are just 2 simple functional components

```
function MyHome({navigation}){  
    //..some states, props, etc

    return (
        <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{/*...some styling*/}}>
            //...some components
        </ScrollView>
    );  

}

function BuyForm({navigation}){ 
    //..some states, props, etc

    return (
        <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{/*...some styling*/}}>
              //...some components
        </ScrollView>
    );              
}
```

My question is : how to hide the root bottom tab navigator when navigating to `BuyForm` component, but not when go to `MyHome` component?

Based from answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60267273/react-navigation-v5-hide-bottom-tabs), i know that i can hide the bottom tab if i put this line `navigation.setOptions({ tabBarVisible: false })` in `MyVeranda` component

```
function MyVeranda({ route,navigation }) {
      //..some states, props, etc
      navigation.setOptions({ tabBarVisible: false })//this hide the bottom tab navigator

      return (
       //...
      )
}
```

But this hide the bottom tab entirely when i am at both `MyHome` and `BuyForm` component.

Calling `navigation.setOptions({ tabBarVisible: false })` in `BuyForm` seems to do nothing

```
function BuyForm({ route,navigation }) {
      //..some states, props, etc
      navigation.setOptions({ tabBarVisible: false }) //this do nothing

      return (
         //...
      )
}
```

So my guess is i have to call `navigation.setOptions({ tabBarVisible: false })` inside `MyVeranda` when `BuyForm` is the active screen, but i cannot the proper syntax to get the current active screen from a stack navigator component?

Comment: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hiding-tabbar-in-screens

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the answer**

[React Navigation how to hide tabbar from inside stack navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51352081/react-navigation-how-to-hide-tabbar-from-inside-stack-navigation/64789273#64789273)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you can use `setOptions` on the navigation to set custom options. Although it's recommended to rather reorganize the navigation structure. This might be possible if you create a `StackNavigator` not nested with the `TabBar`.

```
  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({ tabBarVisible: false });
  }, [navigation]);
```